# How to retrieve one row at a time from the csv file using generator functions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I need to take one row from the CSV file to be used in the reinforcement learning class environment as an observation tuple. I have used generator function first it's not retrieving any data and secondly it will provide all the data iteratively which doesn't match with the requirement of my problem. Also, I need the currently selected observation(CSV row) to be used in multiple methods in the class environment for instance in the reward function.

Any idea or suggestion is highly appreciated on how to do this. Thanks

```
 class Environment1: 
    def __init__(self, data, max_ticks=300):
      self.data = data 
      self.application_latency=1342
      self.reward = 0
      #self.done = False
      self.MAX_TICKS = max_ticks
      self.episode_over = False

    def step(self, act):
      self.take_action(action)
      reward = self.get_reward()
      ob = self.get_state()
      return ob, reward, self.episode_over
      #return  ob, reward, self.done # obs, reward, done

    def get_state(self):
     """Get the observation.  it is a tuple """
     lst = [tuple(x) for x in data.values]
     def gen(last):
       for i in last:
         print(yield i)
         #observation_space= yield i
         #ob = (observation_space.Edge_Latency, observation_space.Cloud_latency )
         #print(ob)
      #return ob
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what I gathered from your question, you want to create a generator of observation tuples from your csv data. Specifically, you want to pass each tuple with `edge latency` and `cloud latency` columns to another function. I have written some example code which will make a list of tuples for each row of your data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def createGenerator(self):
    obs_data = [tuple(x) for x in self.data[['Edge_Latency', 'Cloud_latency']].to_numpy()]
        for obs in obs_data:
            yield obs
```